# jQuery Radio Button Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to show and hide a div. But even in true case else condition executes. I wonder what is my mistake. Thanks for any help in advance.

```js
$(".budget").on("change",function () {
  var radioValue = $(".budget:checked").val();
  if (radioValue=="haveBudget") {
    alert($(this).val());   
  } else {
    alert("else part");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="haveBudget" />
<input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="10" />
```

Comment: You don't have any *else* block in the code.....do you have single radio button?

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code and as mentioned by @Manum there no else statement provided

Comment: Your code ( except some syntax issues and the comparison that should be `===` ) works as intended. see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/0o1mrapd/24/

Comment: You do not needs javascript (or jQuery) for that BTW

Comment: @Mamun I've modified the code. My mistake and I have multiple buttons.

Comment: Consider using input:checkbox is a better and more intuitive alternative for the user and for you the developer

Comment: @aishazafar Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think the code snippet is executing as expected....

Comment: This is working alright on fiddle but not in my document @Mamun

Comment: Then, it might be some other issue....

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some basic changes in your code:

```js
// it's better to use event delegation
$(document).on("change", ".budget", function () {
    var radioValue = this.value; // <-- You have the value because "this" is the input
    
    if( radioValue == 'haveBudget' ){
        console.log('show DIV');
        // do whatever.. show your DIV
    }
    else{
        console.log('hide DIV');
    }
    
    console.log("---- value selected ----", radioValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="haveBudget" />
  <span>Have Budget</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="10" />
  <span>10</span>
</label>
```

Learn more about [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".budget").on("change",function () {
  var radioValue = $(this).val();
  if (radioValue=="haveBudget") {
    alert($(this).val());   
  } else {
    alert("else part");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="haveBudget" />haveBudget
<input type="radio" name="pref" class="budget" value="10" />10
```

Use `this` for accessing value from current object.

Comment: I've used both techniques.

Comment: @aishazafar Then what is the issue are you facing?

Comment: The issue is even in true if condition else part executes.

Comment: @aishazafar can you re-generate that issue in somewhere?